# Show image based on jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code reading an XML file and creating variables from some of the values. This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $.ajax({          
        type:  'GET',
        url:   'https://status.clook.net/xml/status/harvey.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',              
        success: function(xml){
           var http = $(xml).find('http').text();
           var ftp = $(xml).find('ftp').text();
           var mysql = $(xml).find('mysql').text();
           var pop = $(xml).find('pop').text();
           var imap = $(xml).find('imap').text();
           var smtp = $(xml).find('smtp').text();
           var load = $(xml).find('load').text();

          $('.http').html(http);
          $('.ftp').html(ftp);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({          
        type:  'GET',
        url:   'https://status.clook.net/xml/status/email01.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',              
        success: function(xml){
           var ehttp = $(xml).find('http').text();
           var eftp = $(xml).find('ftp').text();
           var emysql = $(xml).find('mysql').text();
           var epop = $(xml).find('pop').text();
           var eimap = $(xml).find('imap').text();
           var esmtp = $(xml).find('smtp').text();
           var eload = $(xml).find('load').text();

          $('.ehttp').html(ehttp);
          $('.eftp').html(eftp);
        }
     });
});
```

This is then being used with the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Server Status Widget</h3>
    <h4>Hosting Server</h4>
    <p>
        <strong>HTTP: </strong>
        <span class="http"></span>
    </p>
    <p>            
        <strong>FTP: </strong>
        <span class="ftp"></span>
    </p>
    <h4>Email Server</h4>
    <p>
        <strong>HTTP: </strong>
        <span class="ehttp"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>FTP: </strong>
        <span class="eftp"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

What I would like to do now is instead of outputting the variable, show an image based on the variable value. I would like to check if the variable value is `OK`, and if so display an image in the span, and then if the variable is anything other to show another image.

For instance if the variable `http` has the value `OK`, in span `.http` to show `allgood.jpg`. If the variable value is anything other than `OK` to show `notgood.jpg`.

Comment: What do you meen - ok?

Comment: which variable value?why there is multiple `document.ready` in code?

Comment: Are images supposed to be loaded from the server as well? Is it loading or appending them which puzzles you?

Comment: Edited to hopefully make it clearer. The image is on my server not being read from where I am getting the XML. The bit that puzzles me is checking the contents of the variable value and changing an image source based on it

Comment: Mike still it is not clear to me,my first question is why two ajax methods for similar activity,why it is not one single function with parameter,second question how the image are stored in server,is it the url?how are that being retrieved in client side?

Comment: There are two ajax methods because I am new to jQuery and am working from examples. Feel free to make any improvements to help me learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ehttp == "ok") {
 var imgsrc = '/images/' + ehttp + '.png';
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 var img.src = imgsrc;
 var target = document.querySelector('.ehttp');
 target.appendChild(img);
}
```

From what I understand of your objective, I'd do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this, with a generalised `showResult()` function to avoid duplication of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fixed data (adapt as necessary)
    var OkText = 'OK';
    var paths = {
        'goodHttp': '/path/to/good/http/image/',
        'badHttp': '/path/to/bad/http/image/',
        'goodFtp': '/path/to/good/ftp/image/',
        'badFtp': '/path/to/bad/ftp/image/'
    };
    // Generalised utility function
    function showResult(containers, xml) {
        var httpText = $(xml).find('http').text();
        var ftpText = $(xml).find('ftp').text();
        if(httpText === OkText) {
            containers.http.html('<img src="' + paths.goodHttp + '"/>');
        } else {
            containers.http.html('<img src="' + paths.badHttp + '"/>');
        }
        if(ftpText === OkText) {
            containers.ftp.html('<img src="' + paths.goodFtp + '"/>');
        } else {
            containers.ftp.html('<img src="' + paths.badFtp + '"/>');
        }
    }

    // AJAX
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://status.clook.net/xml/status/harvey.xml',
        'dataType': 'xml',
    }).then(showResult.bind({
        'http': $("span.http"),
        'ftp': $("span.ftp")
    }));
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://status.clook.net/xml/status/email01.xml',
        'dataType': 'xml',
     }).then(showResult.bind({
        'http': $("span.ehttp"),
        'ftp': $("span.eftp")
    }));
});
```

Note the use of [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to cater for the differences between the two calls.

A better approach might be to hard code the `<img>` elements then change their `src` properties.